# Errors While executing a programs in which client is sending file to server

Tags: java, serversocket

I don't know where i am going wrong in this code , these are client and server program source code.
First i am executed server program which goes fine , but when i executed client program then i got error on both the side (server and Client).
Also new image ( testfile.jpg) is not complete.
i am putting cat.jpg (size 1 MB) file on desktop .

FileClient.java

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class FileClient {

private Socket s;

public FileClient(String host, int port, String file) {
    try {
        s = new Socket(host, port);
        sendFile(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

public void sendFile(String file) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    while (fis.read(buffer) > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer);
    }

    fis.close();
    dos.close();    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileClient fc = new FileClient("localhost", 1988, "cat.jpg");
}
```

}

FileServer.java

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class FileServer extends Thread {

private ServerSocket ss;

public FileServer(int port) {
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Socket clientSock = ss.accept();
            saveFile(clientSock);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void saveFile(Socket clientSock) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(clientSock.getInputStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("testfile.jpg");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    int filesize = 15123; // Send file size in separate msg
    int read = 0;
    int totalRead = 0;
    int remaining = filesize;
    while((read = dis.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(buffer.length, remaining))) > 0) {
        totalRead += read;
        remaining -= read;
        System.out.println("read " + totalRead + " bytes.");
        fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }

    fos.close();
    dis.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileServer fs = new FileServer(1988);
    fs.start();
}
```

}

client side error

```
C:\Users\vishal\Desktop>java FileClient
java.io.FileNotFoundException: cat.jpg (The system cannot find the file 
specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at FileClient.sendFile(FileClient.java:23)
    at FileClient.<init>(FileClient.java:15)
    at FileClient.main(FileClient.java:35)
```

server side error

```
C:\Users\vishal\Desktop>java FileServer
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at FileServer.saveFile(FileServer.java:39)
    at FileServer.run(FileServer.java:23)
```

Comment: One of these exceptions is very clear about what the issue on its end is. Try fixing that, and see if the other error is resolved (hint - it probably will be).

Comment: yeah , cat.jpg is on desktop.

Comment: use absolute path when you attempt to send the file instead of just the name

Comment: I am not getting you. Could you write?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a correct path to your file `cat.jpg` in the main method of your client code.

E.g.

**Replace** the filename in

`FileClient fc = new FileClient("localhost", 1988, "cat.jpg");`

**with** an absolute path such as

`FileClient fc = new FileClient("localhost", 1988, "c:/user/vishal/desktopcat.jpg");`

**or with** a relative path such as

`FileClient fc = new FileClient("localhost", 1988, "../vishal/desktopcat.jpg");`

Note that the relative path will be tricky depending on where you execute your java code. So if you are not sure, use the absolute path.

Once you fix this problem, your client would be able to write the file to the socket at which point your server will stop complaining as well.

Comment: @VishalKrSharma Which one did you try?

Comment: This one "  FileClient fc = new FileClient("localhost", 1988, "c:/user/vishal/desktopcat.jpg");  "

Comment: Do you get the same file not found exception?

Comment: i used " C:\Users\vishal\Desktop\java\cat.jpg" instead of "c:/user/vishal/desktop/java/cat.jpg" .

Comment: You need to use two backslashes in that case to escape a backslash. E.g. c:\\user\\...

Comment: you mean  "C:\\Users\\vishal\\Desktop\\java\\cat.jpg " ?

Comment: i got this on client side  "  
C:\Users\vishal\Desktop\java>java FileServer
read 4096 bytes.
read 8192 bytes.
read 12288 bytes.
read 15123 bytes ".

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: i got it .. the size of the file must be 4 under kb.

Comment: now tell me which digit i want to change in code if i want to send file larger than 4 kb?  There are  three places where  numeric digit is used  in the code (both client and server).

Comment: You need to log a separate question for this as it is no longer related to your original question which is answered now.